# Does Stout apply to the secondary end?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, weapons

I'm a Tempest Fighter, which means I get bonuses out of offhand weapons. If I Power Attack with the secondary end of a double weapon with Stout, do I get the one handed bonus or the two handed bonus?

Comment: Power Attack is never worth it if you do the math. Hitting is more important than damage, especially for a Fighter. Take Weapon Focus instead.

Comment: I'm paragon tier. +6 damage if I get the two handed bonus. And I have combat advantage for every hit after the first so that cancels out the penalty.

Answer (score 5):

Only if the secondary end is Stout.

Let's look at an example. The Urgrosh. Double weapons are really two weapons that share an enchantment, but the two ends have different entries in the compendium, and may have different properties. For the Urgrosh here are the properties of the main end:

Properties

- Defensive
- Stout

Group

- Axe

And the secondary

Properties

- Off hand

Group

- Spear

So for this weapon you can only wield the main end twohanded, not the secondary end. It should be noted here as well that you only get axe feat support for the main end and only get spear feat support for the secondary end. Note that even the spiked chain, which is converted to a double weapon in an ad-hoc sort of way, carries similar wording. Stout is a property typically associated with the main hand of a weapon.